# Firebase Authenticate problems old api

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Hello does any body knows if there is a problem with the api of firebase?. I'm using the old api for two apps and in the authentication form gives me an error how says that its an unknown error, I have saw the code and in the logcat from android studio and it doesn't show nothing referred to this error it worked until 12/06/2018 and know it stop working and I don't have any idea what would it be.

I tried to see if the logcat say something referred but this doesn't show me nothing.

```
            Ref.authWithPassword(email, pass,
                    new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(Inicio.this,Check.class);
                            i.putExtra("Email",email);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                     //       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido.",
                     //               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError error) {

                            switch (error.getCode()) {
                                case FirebaseError.USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario no existe.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                case FirebaseError.INVALID_PASSWORD:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Verifique su contraseña.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                case FirebaseError.NETWORK_ERROR:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Prueba mas tarde, hay un problema con la conexion.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                case FirebaseError.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocurrio un error inesperado, por favor intenta mas tarde.",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    break;
                                default:

                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On December 18 2018 the end points for the oldest Firebase Authentication APIs were retired. This means that apps using the 1.x and 2.x SDKs will no longer work since that day.

The solution is to upgrade your app to a 3.x or later SDK version. For the steps to take, look at [the migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#update_your_authentication_code).

Also see the [announcement](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vpQV8DBQLkIZci7Vh8N4LUHyTkBOsuW5eXE1x8IAqvw/preview#heading=h.nh3bjpr71p53) that was sent to all owners of projects that had active usage on the old API endpoints.

Comment: Thank you very much, you save my day.